# Android 9 keeps shutting my browser tabs on Other User when I just switch to other apps

Tags: android-9, kiwi-browser

I use Kiwi Browser, tried Lemur Browser but they all do it, it's so frustrating cause not only that it refreshes tabs but it shuts them off completely and just when I come back to it it leaves a blank tab open, nothing from my old stuff.

This is on my Other User, where I also don't have Recent Apps shown so I can't just open the browser where I left off.

Comment: Your problem could be unrelated to user switching - it could be a RAM problem: your system may be too old and has too little RAM to keep two instances of a large web browser alive.